# Automated filling in, submission and review of response of javascript form in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, rubygems, mechanize

I'm building a hobby/hack project which needs to cross-reference a users' GMC number with a publicly available source of numbers at http://webcache.gmc-uk.org/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe

The actions need to do the following:
1. Take the number submitted by the user in the application
2. Open http://webcache.gmc-uk.org/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe
3. Post in the number into the GMC Reference Number field
4. Submit the search
5. Retrieve the result and cross reference it with the user details added to ensure they are correct

GMC-UK seem to do everything possible to avoid non-human queries to the data. The form isn't declared as a form and the submit button is in JavaScript, referencing a separate applet which in turn hides as much info as possible.

We've tried using Mechanize but it doesn't support JavaScript. Import.io was another option, but again no support. If someone can physically open the page, enter and submit the info then there **must** be a way of doing this automatically, even if it is tough. Any ideas?

Comment: [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/)

Comment: It can be done with mechanize, you would need to work backward from the request to see what to fill out in the form. If you want something with javascript to make it easier there's selenium, watir-webdriver, capybara, phantomjs, some node.js libs, and a few more.

Comment: @pguardiario still really struggling. This import io attempt sums up the effort they've gone to to prevent scraping: http://youtu.be/MydxlOGgpo4
The page seems to keep reloading each time the window is accessed?

Comment: I'm sure it feels like anti-scraping effort but it's more likely complicated tracking code. Just follow the redirects and you will get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, without some extremely complex programming, this was only possible using Selenium and unfortunately it wasn't reliable enough to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as thought it would be possible using import's connector tool. (it supports JavaScript also) This uses page interactions such as searches and page clicks to display and then extract the data. You can find more information on import.io's connector tool at the link below
http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/247567-create-a-connector

Comment: thanks, we're currently on using selenium and managing the page redirects. Will give import a try after we get it working - more of a learning exercise too. BTW we're at makersacademy - had Matt P come in for a talk a few weeks ago.

Comment: tough/impossible with selenium. Tried import.io and getting this problem - http://youtu.be/MydxlOGgpo4 seems as if they are redirecting the form back each time on purpose?